# Rails - Devise & Doorkeeper OAuth2 how to add a line in body (post request)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, doorkeeper

I'm a new guy trying to learn and catch up on Rails, I was able to make devise and doorkeeper work on my end. Question is, Is it possible to add a new parameter on my post request body? What I would like to happen is, after validating my user and password, i will check my database if the DEVICE(via serial) is existing.

ex.

instead of

```
{
  "grant_type"    : "password",
  "username"      : "test",
  "password"      : "abcd"
}
```

i would like to add the "serial" for validation

ex:

```
{
  "grant_type"    : "password",
  "username"      : "test",
  "password"      : "abcd",
  "serial"        : 12341234
}
```

I'm sorry if this might be a duplicate question, I'm not sure of the right 'keyword' for searching. Thank you very much and it would greatly help me towards my learning.